# webview javascript push value to previous page is not working

Tags: javascript, ios, webview, uiwebview

I've an webpage. I'm using to open webpage.
The first page has a button to show a popup.

On this popup has a list of item. When i click an item, the data will be filled to the first page and the popup close.

On Popup i'm using script "javascript:setvalue(a, b)".
It works fine on Safari iPad or PC browser but not in UIWebview.
I see maybe javascript function is not called.

What should i do, or can anyone point me a way?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString method of UIWebView to leverage your JavaScript function.